# Laptop hinge flat angle fatigue

Tags: laptop, display, hardware-failure, laptop-repair

My laptop is placed in front of my secondary monitor and so I use the laptop's screen in about 30 - 45° angle (0° meaning flat open, 180° closed).

Since now the hinge has to support more weight not pushing directly from top, but rather on a lever, I am wondering, does this reduce the hinge lifespan?

It is the Lenovo Legion 7-16ACHg6 (16", 16:10) so you can check the hinge design.

Comment: If you leave the laptop in place, there's no additional wear on the hinge at all. If you constantly open and close it, *that* will wear the hinge far more than leaving it sitting at a specific angle.

Answer (score 0):

> Since now the hinge has to support more weight not pushing directly
> from top, but rather on a lever, I am wondering, does this reduce the
> hinge lifespan?

Yes, this will stress the hinge. Likely it will lead to early hinge wear out from small movements. We cannot be certain about the latter.

Easy solution:   Get a Dock for your Lenovo machine (Lenovo sells Docks), and operate your computer with the lid closed.

That will work.  I have implemented this approach for lots of people.

Answer (score -1):

All you can do is use another display you can buy a cheap display from amazon. Asus is the best product to use as an external monitor that is not going to cost you a lot.

Comment: OP already has another monitor as they note in the question.